# Xcode6 USB install - pairing is prohibited by a policy on the device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, ios-provisioning

How do I resolve this specific error I am getting with an iPad Air on iOS 8.1 (that might be behind some sort of enterprise/education security protocol)

```
Xcode encountered an error
Pairing is prohibited by a policy on the device
```

N.B. A search currently yields nothing for this specific error message. This seems to be independent of restrictions available in the settings Generals installation restrictions option

Comment: Please describe the type of pairing you are attempting. Attaching a debugger over USB? Attempting to debug over wifi or bluetooth? Pairing a bluetooth device?

Comment: USB install via xcode - updated description

Comment: Do you have any provisioning profiles installed ? Can you look into them ?

Comment: xcode6 should automatically provision right?

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions for this issue,

- You can remove the managed certificate (under Settings --> General --> Profiles & Device Management) installed by the Enterprise. (go to the certificate and it will have a 'Remove Management' or 'Remove Certificate' button)
- If the device is supervised through an Apple Configurator profile, we can ask the Admin/owner to check the option 'Allow devices to connect to other Macs' and in the restrictions check (select) 'Allow pairing with Non-configurator hosts'.
- Another option is to check the 'Restrictions' under the MDM Certificate's details and if the following options are present ask the IT Admin to remove those policies from the device and re-deploy the policy certificate.

  - Installing configuration profiles not allowed
  - Pairing with iTunes not allowed.
  - Establishing untrusted TLS connections not allowed.
  - In-app purchase not allowed.

I believe these should allow the device to be paired with Xcode and another computer.

Answer (score -1):

A "supervised" device could also trigger that error.

Comment: downvote on my answer?! If a device is supervised (Apple Device Enrollment Program) it could actually trigger that error.